# How to make an evenly spaced NSSegmentedControl?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssegmentedcontrol

I have a NSSegmentedControl that I want to set the width and I want this control to fill all the space I have given to it. Also, I want the segments of the NSSegmentedControl to be evenly spaced among all segments (independently of available space or content). How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by two ways:

***Through Interface Builder.***

[image]

***Through Code, for dynamism.***

```
[self.segmentControl setWidth:100 forSegment:0];
```

Do it for all others segment, loop can be used

***EDIT:***

```
- (IBAction)resizeSegmentedControl:(id)sender {

    double segmentControlWidth=self.segmentControl.frame.size.width;

    [self.segmentControl setWidth:segmentControlWidth/3-3 forSegment:0];
    [self.segmentControl setWidth:segmentControlWidth/3-3 forSegment:1];
    [self.segmentControl setWidth:segmentControlWidth/3-3 forSegment:2];

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question... I want to set a width on the NSSegmentedControl and then calculate the width of the segments so the whole NSSegmentedControl fills the space I need it to fill. Let's say that I set NSSegmentedControl width for 150, If I set each segment to 50, due to borders, ect... the control will get clipped.

Comment: I want to add that I was referring to a NSSegmentedControl of 3 segments.

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho: I tried with this, just a small tweak and it worked. see edited answer.

Comment: I need this to work for 1, 2, 3 and 4 segments. Is that code going to work in this scenario?